# Evidence of Gravitational instability viewpoint

Tags: gravity

I'm reading the wikipedia on the [Gravitational instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_instability) and found the content copied from the only reference cited.
The Liddle book 'Introduction to Modern_Cosmology', at page 149 do not explain it.
In the figure A5.1 - representing a valley (a less dense region) surrounded by two crests of denser regions: the matter of the valley will migrate to the crests. The argument is clear from the image, but only a small part of the matter in the universe was selected to draw a conclusion.
[image]

But, using the same simple argument, it appears that the matter in the crests will atract matter from other crests filling in the valleys, because gravity is a long range force.

My argument is that as we extend further to the entire universe the matter that attract any particle we have a 'uniform like' distribution of matter. Only the mean density in the universe is relevant and the voids and filaments are not, as seen in the figure of the 2df redshift survey. (Note that in the outer part of the image the density is the same as in the  region near us. It is whiter only because of our inability to 'see' better.
In the analisys of this problem one can substitute the universe with a mean density field and in this situation any part of the universe being attracted to a crest is compensated by an attraction of the same value in any other outward direction.

So, if we do not limit the problem to the vicinity of the crest by extending outward the region under analisys - the gravity is a long range force that can not be canceled -, we have a **null result** and the universe will must try to cancel the crests.

[image]
How is this gravitational instability explained in clear terms?

Comment: If the crests have about the same mass the intracrest attraction will be larger than the intercrest one, because gravity decreases with distance.

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams You made me understand that a full detail of the problem was needed. I've extended the text. I hope that it is clearer now.  Thanks.

Comment: To see that the crests will not somehow suck matter from other crests go outside: does the Sun suck you off the Earth?  Clearly it does not.  So we have extremely good experimental evidence t hat systems involving clumps of self-gravitating matter with much less dense regions between them are stable fir billions of years once they have formed.  Some study of the behaviour of inverse square forces will show you that initial small variations do indeed get magnified.

Comment: @tfb can you pls turn your comment into an answer ?

Comment: @HelderVelez I need to find some reference about the initial instability before I'm really comfortable with it.

Comment: I'll answer you other question in a few minutes, meanwhile, I am not sure to understand your argument about the mean field. Do you mean this?: "When you zoom out the universe looks smooth, then the net force becomes zero"

Comment: I noticed that in another similar question you mentioned in a comment that any perturbation will be smoothed out, can you support that claim? As far as I understand it is actually the opposite.

Comment: http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~dhw/A825/notes6.pdf

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams yes it is like that: "When you zoom out the universe looks smooth, then the net force becomes zero" And I can add: 1st-any local defect of density will become larger in an accelerated way and 2nd: on the contrary any excess of density will be erased.  The 1st I've substantiated with equations in other post.  Using only gravity in a universe where particles are far appart and the collisions are not very important. As the void grows the matter starts colliding and galaxies are born in the exterior shell (in the intersection)-Tully 2008 and video - Our peculiar motion...

Comment: The universe as low density and as a starting point I' will use a lattice and particles with T=0, and the temperature will grow voids will enlarge.  My sorry is that I'm older now and my gravity program adapted for an infinite universe is outdated by now (was done with Brook+ and now it should be done in OpenCL), but I will try next week.